# Checking for proper input leads to infinite loop

Tags: c++, loops, infinite-loop

Here's the code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    double degree;

    do {
        cout << "Enter a temperature in degrees Celsius: ";
        cin >> degree;
    } while (cin.fail());


    //reassigns degree to conversion to farenheit
    degree = degree * (9/5) + 32;

    cout << "Your temperature in degrees Farenheit is: " << degree;
    return 0;
}
```

If the input is invalid, the program ends up into an infinite loop, constantly repeating the first cout.

I'm kinda new to C++, and I"m  not sure if this is just the compiler acting wonky, or if it's something on my part.

Comment: Wouldn't you want [`cin.eof()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/eof/)?

Comment: what does the eof() function do?

Comment: It explains that on the page I linked.

Comment: Not directly related, but you will soon notice that `(9/5)` is exactly the same as `1` (since integer division ignores remainders). Probably easiest to just type `1.8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `cin.fail()` doesn't do what you think it does. `cin.fail()` tests for *errors* in input. The `eof` (end of file) is not an error in input as far as `cin.fail()` is concerned.

Instead you might want to rewrite as:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    double degree;

    while( (cout << "Enter a temperature in degrees Celsius: ")
            && !(std::cin >> degree)) {
        cout << "you entered in the wrong type, please try again" << endl;
        cin.clear();// clear error flags from cin
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); //extracts characters from the stream and discards them until a newline is found 
    }


    //reassigns degree to conversion to farenheit
    degree = degree * (9.0/5) + 32; //need to do floating point division here

    cout << "Your temperature in degrees Farenheit is: " << degree;
    return 0;
}
```

See this link for more info: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/

Comment: I've tried doing that, but if I enter a non integer/double input, it simply goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: @Retrosaur, see my edit for improved code along with some comments/explanations.